# How to update rows in my database with rows from dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview, row

How to update rows in my database with rows from dataGridView1?

It shows this error:

```
you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '(Time, CarColorNumber, Interior, Exterior, CPlastic,...)
```

this is the code that I have so far:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach ( DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string constring = "Data Source = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 0159";
            string Query = " Update TopShineDB.Table1 (Time, CarColorNumber, Interior, Exterior, CPlastic, MPlastic, SPlastic, PlasticB, WashExt, WashEng, WashTrunk, WashSeats, SeatsRmv, SeatsFit, Notes) VALUES ('" + dr.Cells[0] + "','" + dr.Cells[1] + "','" + dr.Cells[2] + "','" + dr.Cells[3] + "','" + dr.Cells[4] + "','" + dr.Cells[5] + "','" + dr.Cells[6] + "','" + dr.Cells[7] + "','" + dr.Cells[8] + "','" + dr.Cells[9] + "','" + dr.Cells[10] + "','" + dr.Cells[11] + "','" + dr.Cells[12] + "','" + dr.Cells[13] + "','" + dr.Cells[14] + "')";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Table Successfully Updated");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: What error exactly? can you add the error to the question please?

Comment: @scartag already updated

Comment: Consider learning how data binding works. If you are plucking data out of a UI element you are doing too much work. If  you data bound correctly and had a data adapter, you could just call `Update()` instead of the complex and injection prone way you are getting your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string Query = " Update TopShineDB.Table1 (Time, CarColorNumber, Interior, Exterior, CPlastic, MPlastic, SPlastic, PlasticB, WashExt, WashEng, WashTrunk, WashSeats, SeatsRmv, SeatsFit, Notes) VALUES ('" + dr.Cells[0] + "','" + dr.Cells[1] + "','" + dr.Cells[2] + "','" + dr.Cells[3] + "','" + dr.Cells[4] + "','" + dr.Cells[5] + "','" + dr.Cells[6] + "','" + dr.Cells[7] + "','" + dr.Cells[8] + "','" + dr.Cells[9] + "','" + dr.Cells[10] + "','" + dr.Cells[11] + "','" + dr.Cells[12] + "','" + dr.Cells[13] + "','" + dr.Cells[14] + "')";

The SQL above is not a valid update statement.. The correct UPDATE syntax should be:-

```
UPDATE TopShineDB.Table1 
SET Time = '" + dr.Cells[0] + "', 
Notes = '"+ dr.Cells[14] + "' 
WHERE Table1ID = ID from the grid
```

Let me know is that doesn't work

Comment: may I know what you mean by "ID from the grid" ?

Comment: and just to clarify, it should be written like this?   "Update TopShineDB.Table1 SET Time = '" + dr.Cells[0] + "', ........... , Notes = '"+ dr.Cells[14] + "' WHERE Table1ID = ID from the grid "